# I have a List with region of numbers and i want to build a List of all the numbers how can i do it?

Tags: c#

I have a List wich is looks like this:

```
in index[0] "Test 0 Length 32 [41 - 73]"
in index[1] "Test 1 Length 22 [81 - 103]"
```

And so on.

I need to get the all the numbers from each index. For example in the new List i need to have: 41,42,43,44,45,46,47....73 then to take the numbers from index[1] and after the 73 in he new List to continue 81,82,83,84,85....103

So the new List wich will be  will contain all the numbers.

To calculate the Length for example 32 or 22 im doing:

```
int len = LR[i].end - LR[i].start;
```

Lr[i].end is 73 and Lr[i].start is 41

So i need to calculate and get all the numbers between 41 and 73 including 41 and 73 and add them to a new List then to the next itertion where LR[i].end is 103 and start is 81 and again get the numbers and add them to the List

So in the end the List will contain all the numbers in one big row.

How can i do it ?

Comment: Can you show the contents of LR?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<string> list = new List<string>()
{
    "Test 0 Length 32 [41 - 73]",
    "Test 1 Length 22 [81 - 103]"
};

var numbers = 
   list.SelectMany(
          s => Regex.Matches(s, @"\[(\d+)[ -]+(\d+)\]")
               .Cast<Match>()
               .Select(m => m.Groups.Cast<Group>().Skip(1).Select(x=>x.Value)
                                                          .ToArray())
               .Select(x => new {start=int.Parse(x[0]), end=int.Parse(x[1]) })
               .SelectMany(x => Enumerable.Range(x.start, x.end- x.start + 1))
        )
       .ToList();
```

Comment: Nice, but your first Select seems redundant. Why not just access the groups directly in the next Select?

Comment: @Rawling Just to make it more readible. In fact, two `select`s and `SelectMany` can be combined too. (See the first version of the answer)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the contents of LR is, but I assume that you have your range numbers as a valid ints (otherwise, you will have to use regex or String.IndexOf to find them).

But, if you have list of object where object looks like this:

```
class pairs
{  
int item1;   
int item2;    
}
```

then you can easily do the following (see [Enumerable.Range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx))
Enumerable.Range accepts two parameters: start and count. To get the count we have to subtract upper-bound from lower bound and add one to include upper-bound value.:

```
var values = new List<int>();
list.ForEach(x =>values.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(x.Item1, x.Item2 - x.Item1 + 1)));
```

Working console app using [Tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx):

```
var list = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
            list.Add(Tuple.Create(41, 73));
            list.Add(Tuple.Create(81, 103));
            list.Add(Tuple.Create(120, 150));
            // So, now we have three pair of values.   41-73, 81-103, 120-150

            //Now we can loop through the list and generate sequence using Enumerable.Range like this: 
            var values = new List<int>();
           list.ForEach(x =>values.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(x.Item1, x.Item2 - x.Item1 + 1)));

            //And print out items.
            values.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
            //will print 41,42,43......73, 81,82,83....,103, 120, 121,.....150
```

Answer (score 0):

SelectMany will give you a concatenated sequence of subsequences, so the following would give you a list of all the numbers in each range.

```
ranges.SelectMany(r => Enumerable.Range(r.start, r.end - r.start + 1)).ToList();
```